# How do you handle fixed width layouts when the background color stretches across the entire page

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a page wherein, globally, there is a fixed-width so that all content is centered in the middle of the screen, as if everything is contained in a wrapper. In the example below, the parent div's `max-width` is set to 500px.

Some sections on this site have background colors or background images that need to stretch across the entire width of the page as in the example of the blue-colored `div` below. I've set this `div` to `position:absolute` to go beyond the width setting of its parent.

But what if I want to have content that is contained within the blue `div`, and I want this content to abide by the global fixed-width setting of 500px? In the example below, you can see that the green `div` does not sit within the `max-width: 500px;` setting, and instead inherits the width of its immediate parent, the blue `div`.

Is there any way to make the green `div` follow the global `max-width`?

```html
<div style="max-width: 500px; height: 1000px; background-color: red; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: blue; left: 0; top: 50px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: green; top: 50px;">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

For example, the background of that middle div stretches across the width of the page. It contains contents that has a fixed-width, though.

Comment: Not if you're nesting them this way. the green div is `position: absolute;` and that will be positioned relative to it's closest non-`static` positioned ancestor (the blue div). I'm not sure what the actual end goal is though. Maybe you can draw a picture of what your end goal is and we can offer a different approach?

Comment: Thanks - I've attached a picture and some more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the green div: width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: green; margin: 50px auto 0px auto;

if you realy want it that way, but i would suggest you dont nest the blue div in the red one.

Comment: Even though that would work, I'm looking for an option where pretty much all the content on the page is contained within a single wrapper with a `max-width` of, say, 500px. I don't if that's the right way to go about it, though.

Comment: And the only elements that go beyond this `max-width` setting are ones like background images or colors that stretch across the whole page.

Comment: Then i would center the content with auto margins

Comment: If the red `div` were a `body` tag trying to set a global `max-width`, I guess that gets cancelled out with divs like the blue div. I want to avoid adding a wrapper for every single section, you know? But..I guess that might be the only way to do it?

Comment: Like, rather than trying to have a global `max-width` set, maybe I should just have individual wrappers for each section? That seems excessive, but maybe that's just how it's done?

Comment: I do think thats a better approach.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.